# Word/phrase for copying down incorrectly

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe when someone copies something down incorrectly.

Specifically, the situation I am thinking about is when someone is solving a problem (using pencil and paper), and in one step, they incorrectly copy an equation or expression from their previous step:

> Joe Smith got 1 point off on his math homework for a ____ [error] when
>   he accidentally changed a 7 to a 1.

I originally arrived at the phrase "typographical error", however when I looked this up it seemed to only apply in the case of printing or typing (as in using a keyboard or typewriter), and does not seem to apply when writing with pencil, nor does it quite convey an issue with *copying* from a previous step.

Is there a more appropriate phrase that I can use?

EDIT: I'm specifically looking for a noun (or noun phrase) that can be used in the same way that "typographical error" is used.

Comment: I generally use "tupo".  Alas, few people know what "finger check" means anymore.

Comment: You might reconsider what the student was really marked down for.  Presumably, the error led to an incorrect final answer, and that was why s/he lost a point.  Or rather, the teacher must have recognised that but for this silly slip, s/he would have got it right and decided only to take one mark off.

Comment: Math teacher here. I call this a "writeo", a coinage based on "typo". (Side note: I would seek to give full credit if the student simply misread the 7 as a 1, as long as this did not make the problem significantly easier.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I immediately thought of *typo* but that doesn't include the possibility that Joe incorrectly *believed* it was a 1 that he saw—and so deliberately recorded it as such.

A more appropriate word is [**mistranscription**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistranscription).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : a mistake in transcription : an incorrect copy
> // an unlikely word that was probably a *mistranscription*

And from Merriam-Webster's definition of [*transcribe*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcribe) itself:

> **1 a** : to make a written copy of
> **b** : to make a copy of (dictated or recorded matter) in longhand or on a machine (such as a typewriter)
> **c** : to paraphrase or summarize in writing
> **d** : write down, record

Comment: 'miscopy' is also a word, but it looks weird.

Comment: *Transcription* is not copying down.

Comment: I would say "... for a *transcription error* ...".

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***[miscopy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/miscopy):***

> to copy incorrectly:
>
> - to miscopy an address.

(Dictionary.com)

***Miscopy is also a noun*** meaning: *an incorrect copy*

From [A Companion to Paleopathology](https://books.google.it/books?id=lkgxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&dq=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikjqKHyOfeAhVD-YUKHbYPATIQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&f=false) 2016:

> It might have been a genuine word of the time, or ***a miscopy of the manuscript due to scruffy handwriting.***

From [The Greig-Duncan folk song collection](https://books.google.it/books?id=i5QwAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&dq=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigwN-OyefeAhVLWsAKHfMxDTkQ6AEIOzAF)  :

> "Heary peary" at 1 1 .3 is probably ***a miscopy of "Heavy heavy"***.

and from
[Handbook of American Indians North of Mexico](https://books.google.it/books?id=8qWVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA329&dq=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjevMX0yefeAhWHM-wKHdYID_QQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22a%20miscopy%20of%22&f=false):

> The designation of this mission as “Purísima Concepción de los Asinais'' came from ***a miscopy of the word “ Ainai''*** in Mem. de Nueva España, xxv II, fol. 163

Answer (score 0):

*(a) **miscopying** (of s.t.)*

> Censorinus wrote that Aristarchus of Samos reckoned a Great Year of 2484 years: it has been argued that this is a **miscopying** of 2434, which represents 45 Exeligmos cycles. (emphasis mine)
>   <sup>"[Great Year -- Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Year#Description)", WP</sup>

"(A) *miscopying* (of s.t.)" is already in regular use in genetics.

> Joe Smith got 1 point off on his math homework for a **miscopying** when he accidentally changed a 7 to a 1.

I'd have loved *miscopyment* but it seems it's only the copyright attorneys who use the term *copyment*.

> Writer hereby specifically reserves to herself those parts of the **copyment** that do not concem musical compositions or parts of musical compositions written by the songwriter … (emphasis mine)
>   <sup>("Hastings communications and entertainment law journal, XVIII, p.[151](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KANNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22copyment%22&dq=%22copyment%22)," GoogleBooks)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

**Wrongly copied** can be used to express this.